# CMS for Extranet, Forms

Tags: forms, content-management-system, extranet

I'm looking for a CMS for our extranet.  We need users to be able to authenticate themselves and we'll want to design forms that submit data to a database.  Just wondering what CMS systems people can suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the majority of CMS systems can accomplish creation of simple HTML forms for data capture purposes.  I guess it really depends on what you want to do with the forms - how complex are they?  What do you need to do with the data afterwards?

I have experience with Ektron and can tell you that everything you want to do is possible with Ektron.  You can setup Ektron to authenticate against Active Directory to enable Single Sign On for your users.  Ektron users can create HTML forms for other users to use to submit data too.

It also depends on your budget - there are several open source CMS packages that you may also want to consider.